# How to rewrite the code to avoid using SqlContext.read() in Spark 1.3.1?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Our project used to be developed on Spark 1.4.0, and now we want to migrate it to another cluster, which needs a special Spark JAR whose version is 1.3.1. When we replaced the JAR, we found the following code doesn't work anymore:

```
val dataFrame = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
  .options(getOptionProperties(request.Options))
  .schema(schema)
  .load(request.FilePath)
```

It turns out that `read` is available only after 1.4. So how can I rewrite the code to get the equilavent result?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from 1.4.0 [SQLContext Documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/SQLContext.html) .

> load(String source, StructType schema, java.util.Map options)
>
> Deprecated.  As of 1.4.0, replaced by
>
> read().format(source).schema(schema).options(options).load().

So i guess you can use

```
load("com.databricks.spark.csv", schema, getOptionProperties(request.Options))
```

to obtain the same result.

Comment: Thank you, I did this and I added `"path" -> request.FilePath` in the `options`, and it works well.

Answer (score 0):

To read CSV into a dataframe, you need this 3rd party package https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv

The document is pretty clear on Spark 1.3